# How to display player turn in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Beginner programmer here. In my controller constructor I have:

```
vm.turnCounter = 0;
vm.turn = getTurn();

function getTurn() {
            if (vm.turnCounter % 2 == 0) {
                return 'Player 1';
            } else {
                return 'Player 2';
            }
        }
```

vm is my capture variable, I'm not using $scope. I'm trying to display the current turn in my view with `{{ctrl.turn}}` but so far changes in `vm.turnCounter` has no effect on `{{ctrl.turn}}`, it always displays "Player 1". Am I missing some Angular databinding concepts here? Thanks.

Here's the whole controller, I omitted the super long `getBoards()` because it's just a long array I'll put in firebase:

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('APP')
        .controller('TicTacToeCtrl', TicTacToeCtrl);

    function TicTacToeCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.addPiece = addPiece;
        vm.boards = getBoards();
        vm.turnCounter = 0; //encapsulate this
        vm.turn = 'Player 1';
        vm.getTurn = getTurn();

        function addPiece(obj) {
            if (obj.p1 || obj.p2)
                obj.p1 = true;
            vm.turnCounter++;
        }

        function getTurn() {
            if (vm.turnCounter % 2 == 0) {
                return 'Player 1';
            } else {
                return 'Player 2';
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Well, you need to use $scope if you want your view to have access to it. Post your whole controller code

Comment: Thanks, I just posted my full controller.

Comment: what is `vm` and why do you not want to use $scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified answer: http://jsfiddle.net/jd96d6kr/

In order for your view to know what is going on you are going to have to use `$scope`. That is the whole point of data binding in angular. Change `var vm` to `$scope.vm`

```
<body ng-app="APP">
<div ng-controller="TicTacToeCtrl">
    <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
    turn is {{vm.turn}}
</div>
```

```
(function()
{
  angular
  .module('APP',[])
  .controller('TicTacToeCtrl', function($scope)
  {
    $scope.vm = this;
    $scope.vm.addPiece = $scope.addPiece;
    $scope.vm.turnCounter = 0;
    $scope.vm.turn = 'Player 1';

    $scope.addPiece = function(obj)
    {
      if (obj.p1 || obj.p2)
        obj.p1 = true;
      $scope.vm.turnCounter++;
    }

    $scope.getTurn = function()
    {
      console.log($scope.vm.turnCounter);
      return ($scope.vm.turnCounter % 2 == 0) ? 'Player 1' : 'Player 2';
    }

    $scope.next = function()
    {
      $scope.vm.turnCounter++;
      $scope.vm.turn = $scope.getTurn();
    }
  });
})();
```

I'm not sure what `addPiece()` does, so I didn't really do much with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronnie, works great! I learned Angular with $scope but I'm making a transition from it as suggested here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide
Thanks for the help!

Comment: which part of that guide is suggesting not to use scope? What can I ctrl-f for?

Comment: "controllerAs View Syntax" will find it. I ended up solving this without $scope, but when the controller constructor is called, it calls my function to change to player 2. Minor problem, not a big deal.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't seen it done this way but I could see how it would be useful in some instances